# Matrix invertible if $0, 1, 2, 3$ or $0,1,2, —3$? in every row? Each row adds to $0$? (Strang P92 2.5.35)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Could a 4 by 4 matrix $A$ be invertible if every row contains the numbers $0,1,2,3$ in
>   some order? What if every row of $B$ contains $0,1,2, —3$ in some order?
>
> **Answer:** A can be invertible with diagonal zeros. $B$ is singular because each row adds to zero.

$\Large{1.}$ Sadly, the answer doesn't impart how and why they discovered that $A$?

$\Large{2.}$ I savvy that the summation of each row of $B$ ($0,1,2, —3$ in some unknown order) $= 0$.
But how and why does this prove that $B$ is singular?

$\Large{3.}$ What is the operation/technique/trick in #2 for $B$? Since nothing is solved for, it doesn't sound like Gaussian or Gauss-Jordan Elimination? How and why can each row of a matrix be added to each other to produce a number (out of a matrix)?

---

**Supplement to Prof Shifrin's Answer:**

$\Large{1.1.}$ Since $RREF(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}) = Id$, I see that your $A$ is invertible. However, I still don't apprehend how you contrived your $A$, so could you please reveal how?

$\Large{3.1.}$ While I grasp your first paragraph, I'm now fretting about the multiplication of $A$ by $(1, 1, 1, 1 )$ vs the solution's addition of each row; they seem like different methods to me. Are they? If they are truly disparate, could you also please expound on their method?

Answer (score 2):

For B, note that if you multiply the matrix by the vector $x=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ you get $0$. Thus, $N(B) \ne \{0\}$ and this means $B$ is singular. (Remember that one criterion for nonsingularity/invertibility is that $Bx=0$ have *only* the $0$ solution.)

For A, you just need to think about row operations if you put the entries in by trial and error:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$
is nonsingular/invertible because its reduced echelon form is the identity matrix.

Comment: Many thanks. +1. Could you please respond to the supplementary in my OP? Apologies for the delay.

Comment: For the second, multiplying by a vector dots that vector with each of the rows, hence adds up its entries. For the first, I literally did it "at random" and then checked the rank. Perhaps you'd prefer something more methodical, like cyclic permutations: $$\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&3&0\\2&3&0&1\\3&0&1&2\\0&1&2&3\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you again. Could you please illuminate how and why one would foreknow/prevision to appeal to cyclic permutations? I wouldn't have envisioned their role in $A$! Also, could you please respond in your answer and not as comment (to avoid content breakage)?